# PHP Regex - find word and get everything until character

Tags: php, regex, character, preg-match

Im trying to find a regex pattern that matches a string, and return everything after that string until '/'. I currently have:

```
'/forums\/topic\/\s*([^\/]*)/u'
```

but this returns everything including 'forums/topic/'

Example: string:

```
equest lorem ipsum dawhdk scripts. Problem: a href="__;_base_url_j;p_i;oj/index.php?/forums/topic/975-example-maps-to-local-rating/" then does something,
```

I only need "975-example-maps-to-local-rating"

Comment: Simplify your expression: Use something other than `/` for the pattern delimiter, then you won't have to escape it in the pattern.

Comment: Your regexp works here: https://regex101.com/r/vv6f9P/1

Comment: It sounds like you're looking at the entire match instead of just capture group 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pat = '=forums/topic/\s*([^/]*)=u';
$str = 'equest lorem ipsum dawhdk scripts. Problem: a href="__;_base_url_j;p_i;oj/index.php?/forums/topic/975-example-maps-to-local-rating/" then does something,';

preg_match($pat, $str, $match);

var_dump($match);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "forums/topic/975-example-maps-to-local-rating"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "975-example-maps-to-local-rating"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
.*/(.*)/
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/gAInnx/2)**

Php code

```
$re = '~.*/(.*)/~';
$str = 'equest lorem ipsum dawhdk scripts. Problem: a href="__;_base_url_j;p_i;oj/index.php?/forums/topic/975-example-maps-to-local-rating/" then does something, ';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```